# PHP comillas simples en un echo

Tags: php, html

Quiero mostrar las comillas simples dentro de un `echo`

```
$email = "correo@correo.com";
echo 'mail->addAddress('.$email.')';
```

Tiene que salir así:

```
mail->addAddress('correo@correo.com');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa comillas dobles fuera y simples dentro:

```
$email = "correo@correo.com";
echo "mail->addAddress('$email');";
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Q6tOvJ)

Con las comillas simples imprime literales. Con las dobles imprime el contenido y sus variables.

Ej:

- `echo '$email'` imprime `"$email"`
- `echo "$email"` imprime `"correo@correo.com"`

Tambien puedes usar el caracter de escape como pone Diego en su respuesta.

Comment: La variable email no se puede modificar.

Comment: A que te refieres, @Trackless ? A la funcion `addAddress`?  Tu pregunta es sobre como imprimir con [tag:php] ... lo demás de tu codigo no se puede saber ya que tu pregunta no lo recoge

Comment: mail->addAddress('correo@correo.com'); Es el como me gustaría que se mostrara.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Bien. Esto es como en Bash y tantas otras: las variables no se expanden dentro de comillas simples, pero sí dentro de comillas dobles.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el carácter de escape /:

```
$email = "correo@correo.com";
echo 'mail->addAddress(\''.$email.'\')';
```

O también usando las comillas dobles en por fuera:

```
$email = "correo@correo.com";
echo "mail->addAddress('$email')";
```

Además en este segundo ejemplo no necesitas usar la concatenación, pues PHP busca dentro de la cadena si hay variables que imprimir.